# Juniper JunOS routing issue in v15.1.49

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, cisco-nexus

I have a Cisco Nexus that has a few vlans on it - total network size is 172.26.64.0/20 split into /24 vlans - each using the third octet as the vlan ID.
It's IP is 172.26.x.254 on each vlan as the default gateway.

I have a Juniper SRX cluster, with one of the reth interfaces connected on 172.26.64.246, with interface subnet of /20.

On the Juniper, i have also configured a static route of 172.26.64.0/20 which points at the Nexus as next hop.

From the SRX, i can ping the Nexus on it's addresses of the .64 range.

However, i cannot ping anything on the .66.x range, or .67.x range, and nothing can ping the SRX UNLESS it is on the .64.x vlan.

My question is this...

I removed the following route from the SRX:

`set routing-options static route 172.26.64.0/20 next-hop 172.26.64.254`

and replaced it with:

`set routing-options static route 172.26.64.0/24 next-hop 172.26.64.254
set routing-options static route 172.26.65.0/24 next-hop 172.26.64.254
set routing-options static route 172.26.66.0/24 next-hop 172.26.64.254
set routing-options ....`

That now works - e.g. from a host on 172.26.66.x network, i can ping the SRX on 172.26.64.246 and vice versa.

Why? is this a defect\bug in JUNOS?

For note - The Juniper version is 15.1X49-D30.3

Comment: so if  you revert back the issue still occurs right? can you share the rt during that instance. also share  the config or routing-options with pipe display-inheritance to make sure nothing is being carried from a group config

Comment: Yes, correct - reverting it back shows the issue. Tried it a few times with continuous ping. 
There is no group config - it's a fresh build\config. I cant get the routing table currently, however it is as simple as above.

Comment: Have you tried changing the subnet on your reth interface to a /24?

Comment: No, but that's it! All hosts on any vlan are set as /24, and the SRX should be no different in this case.  I will give it a go if I can when I'm back at that network. Then, if it needs to get to the other vlans the Nexus will accommodate it. Cheers!

Comment: @A-A-Ron another great comment you should convert to an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the subnet mask on your reth interface from a /20 to a /24.